# Gridview first position called repeatedly when scroll gridview

Tags: gridview, android-arrayadapter

I am wondering why the view in first position is repeatedly called when I scroll the gridview even when I set the adapter. This causes my gridview cannot be scrolled smoothly as it repeatedly reload image.

It seems `Picasso.with(context).load(file).into(viewImage);` causes the repeatedly called because if I delete this line, the gridview can be scrolled smoothly.

Any suggestions for improvement? Thanks.

Implementation for gridview array adapter

```
class HomeBrandCVC extends ArrayAdapter<Brand> {

private Context context;
private ArrayList<Brand> brandArrayList;
private Map<Integer, File> fileMap = new HashMap<>();

public HomeBrandCVC(Context c, ArrayList<Brand> brandArrayList) {
    super(c, R.layout.homecvc, brandArrayList);
    this.context = c;
    this.brandArrayList = brandArrayList;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    final View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.homecvc, parent, false);
    TextView nameLabel = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.homecvc_nameLabel);
    nameLabel.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    final Brand brand = brandArrayList.get(position);
    nameLabel.setText(brand.name);
    ImageView viewImage = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.homecvc_viewImage);

    Log.d("hellllo", String.valueOf(position));

    if (fileMap.containsKey(position)) {
        viewImage.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileMap.get(position).getAbsolutePath()));
    } else {
        viewImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.loadingimage);
        new MyLeanCloudApp.GetImageFromDiskOrUrl(brand.imageFile, new MyLeanCloudApp.ImageHandlerGetImagesResponse() {
            @Override
            public void processFinish(File file) {
                if (context != null) {
                    if (file != null) {
                        Picasso.with(context).load(file).into(viewImage);
                        fileMap.put(position, file);
                    }
                }
            }
        }).execute();
    }
    return rowView;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Always try to use `ViewHolder` Pattern for lists and girds. This will improves the performance of Lists and Grids. Other think its not only depend on [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) but its also depend on your image url, you  in you xml layout file, loading data, etc.

Try to use `ViewHolder` to avoid scrolling issue and improves its performance

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
    if(convertView==null){
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item,parent,false);

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }
    else {
        viewHolder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }
    viewHolder.image=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
    viewHolder.title=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
    viewHolder.title.setText(Html.fromHtml(values.getPosts().get(position).getTitle()));

    imageView.setImageResource(Imageid[position]);
    return convertView;
}

private static class ViewHolder{
    public static ImageView image;
    public static TextView title;
}
```

Other think is try to load your image from cash if its previously loaded when you are using Picasso. For that check this [tutorial](https://blog.fossasia.org/cache-thumbnails-and-images-using-picasso-in-open-event-android/).